# Вопрос о склонении фамилии Гамезо

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте, меня зовут Гамезо Роман.
Недавно моя классная руководительница задалась таким вопросом: можно ли склонять мою фамилию?
Она и все мои одноклассники говорят о том, что фамилия склоняется, и приводят как доводы данные из справочников.
В последних говориться, что если фамилия иностранная, то склонять её нельзя, а если нет - то можно.
Если верить истории нашей семьи, то эта фамилия появилась в результате сокращения при переселении моих предков с территории захваченной советской Красной Армией Польши вглубь Беларуси.
До этого фамилия была иностранной (получилась в слиянии двух семей - испанских и итальянских аристократов) и звучала как "Гальмеццо".
В ходе регистрации в СССР фамилию, повторюсь, сократили, и получился современный вариант.
Так всё-таки, склоняется моя фамилия или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Я готов бы даже с Розенталем поспорить (потому, что многие фамилии на ударяемый -А/-Я по факту склоняются, а украинские на -ко сколонялись только в XIX веке), но это не имеет решительно никакого отношения к фомилии Гамезо. Увы, но орфографическое О, даже безударное, т.е. соответствующее фонетическому А, исключает все разговоры о склоняемости. Смените фамилию на Гамеза - и склоняете себе в удовольствие.

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя говорится, что иностранные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на гласный звук (кроме неударяемых -а, -я, с предшествующим согласным) не склоняются. Украинские фамилии на -ко (-енко) в художественной литературе обычно склоняются. Ваша фамилия имеет явно не славянское происхождение. Она не должна склоняться.

Answer (score 0):

Украинские фамилии на "-ко" склоняются в украинском языке, в русском же - нет. И, само собой, Ваша фамилия не склоняется, никого не слушайте.